# ERROR: Cannot install -r requirements.txt (line 40) and tensorboard==2.0.2 because these package versions have conflicting dependencies

Tags: python, tensorflow

While installing the requirements I am getting the error Cannot install -r requirements.txt (line 40) and tensorboard==2.0.2 because these package versions
have conflicting dependencies.

The conflict is caused by:
The user requested tensorboard==2.0.2
tensorflow 2.3.1 depends on tensorboard<3 and >=2.3.0
[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qVhVe.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ixOw4.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Zpak.png)

Comment: What is confusing about the error? You cannot install `tensorboard 2.02` with `tensorflow 2.3.1` You will need to update the `requirements.txt` file. If you created the file try using `pip list --format=freeze > requirements.txt` to create it

Answer (score 0):

You have to update your `requirements.txt`. Tensorflow requires a higher version of tensorboard package to be able to be installed. You have to either remove it from your `requirements.txt` or update the version.